# How do I use PUT in RestSharp?

Tags: c#, restsharp

I want to use PUT, but I can only find examples of how to use POST. The json data I want to send is sent using this cURL command `curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d {"status":1}'http://192.168.0.3:1337/auto/api/v1.0/relays/3` Also I want the "1" after status and the last "3" to be variables.

Comment: Just use `Method.PUT` in the `RestRequest` and use RestSharp like you would do with other methods.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Set the method as you create the rest request:

```
public void Update(int id, Product product)
{
  var request = new RestRequest("Products/" + id, Method.PUT);
  request.AddJsonBody(product);
  client.Execute(request);
}
```

([Source](https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2015/10/01/consume-a-webapi.aspx))

---

(Aircode Warning)

```
  var status = 1;
  var id = 3;
  var request = new RestRequest("/auto/api/v1.0/relays/" + id, Method.PUT);
  request.AddJsonBody(new { status = status });
  client.Execute(request);
```

([Compiling Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/jx8ZE2))

Comment: `Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.` on `"status"` and two `Syntax error, ',' expected` one before `:` and one before `status`

Comment: Try now. I fixed it in my fiddle, but forgot to post the updated one here. Mea culpa.

Comment: That fixed it, Thanks!