# RestSharp PUT request parameters

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp

I'm having issues figuring out how to create a put request using RestSharp.

I need to pass an integer followed by a JSON body in the same request.

So far I have this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ReorderedTasks.Count; i++) {
            var reorderedTasksJson = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ReorderedTasks[i]);
            var request = new RestRequest("api/task/5/{ID}/", Method.PUT);
            request.AddParameter("ID", ReorderedTasks[i].ID.ToString(), ParameterType.UrlSegment);
            request.AddParameter("application/json; charset=utf-8", reorderedTasksJson, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            client.Execute(request);
        }
```

I've tested out the JSON ad requestBody on POST and it works fine.  I think my issue is with the first parameter I'm trying to pass `ReorderedTasks[i].ID` , I'm not sure if I'm handling the passing of this correctly.

I've initialised client at the beginning of my class.

Problem is the DB isn't updating and I need to isolate the problem.  Is the above the correct way in dealing with my two parameters needing passed?

Comment: and the problem is ?

Comment: See updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to put ReorderedTasks[i].ID.ToString() directly to url path.

```
var request = new RestRequest($"api/task/5/{ReorderedTasks[i].ID.ToString()}/", Method.PUT);
```

It will help to reduce possible problems with http request format.

Comment: Great. I did not realise I could do this.  Will try and get back.

Answer (score 1):

I'll add it here, so someone will benefit from it.

If your endpoint URL have parameters like `?param=value&param2=value` that you want to pass along with request RestSharp's `AddParameter(string, string)` won't work with `PUT` method (but it works just fine with `GET` or if endpoint doesn't have URL parameters, so it is deceiving)

Use `AddParameter(string, string, ParameterType.QueryString)` in order to `PUT` Method work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends on what does the webApi expect..

You could use Fiddler to inspect what being sent through the wire and what response You are getting (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)

Also - here are some sample's how other users use RestSharp
[How do I use PUT in RestSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35246586/how-do-i-use-put-in-restsharp)

Comment: API expects a long and json body.  Thank you I will look into your suggestion.